# Simple login system issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a simple login/signup system using `php` but my code won't seem to find the database entry when i try to log in even though its there.

here's my code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn - > connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
    }

    $error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
    if (isset($_POST["submitL"])) {
        if (empty($_POST["usernameL"]) || empty($_POST["passwordL"])) {
            $error = "Both fields are required.";
        } else {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username = $_POST['usernameL'];
            $password = $_POST['passwordL'];

            // To protect from MySQL injection
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
            $password = md5($password);

            //Check username and password from database
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM MyGuests WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            //If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
            //Otherwise echo error. 

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['usernameL'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
                header("location: /account.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            } else {
                $error = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I always get the `Incorrect username or password`-error on return

Comment: Your code is wide open to `SQL injection`, also using `MD5` for storing passwords is not a good idea. Please consider using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to store passwords in a database

Comment: do an `echo $password` after `$password = md5($password);` and check if that will equal to the one save in the database

Comment: I suggest you first echo your final `$username` and `$password`, just to make sure that what they show is what you are really expecting

Comment: @DarkBee I did a basic php course and im still learning. Thanks for the input

Answer (score -1):

I found my mistake!
I used username and password as variables. Changing the username and password in the first few lines of code fixed it for me